# For time-lapse videos, what software should one use?

Tags: video, software, video-editor

I have the following starting position:

I have a GoPro Hero 2 and have done some timelapse series. I took them and stitched them together with the software that go pro provides. This all worked well.

The Problem:

As soon as i want to watch these videos somewhere else, I can't. The software uses some codec apparently belonging to GoPro and obviously most common players won't play anything.
I already tried to convert the video to a wider accepted format(codec) but I wouldn't get anything I could watch. It either only used the first view pictures and then went black or 
the video was entirely black.

The Question:

Now my question is should I use an other program or is there any easy way to convert my current work into a format(codec) that is wider spread. What software would you suggest to use in such a case. This is only a hobby project so I'm not prepared to spend unreasonable amounts on fully fledged software suites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally got time and dug around. I unearthed multiple options to do a timelapse video, but the one I found best is actually the following:

The answer is so simple, I just didn't know a time-lapse video could be created with [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Here is how you do it and you can install and use your very own and wanted codec: [manual](http://timelapseblog.com/2009/08/04/using-virtualdub-for-time-lapse/)

You can then work on the time-lapse movie with a video editor of your choice.

Comment: Well, I just think that Dr Mayhem answered it the best. This is because with VirtualDub, you don't have the opportunity to do much more than just putting a series of images into a movie. With GoPro Hero 2 you also have the option to do a bit more than that to make a good time lapse. Thus, converting it to QuickTime or anything else would probably be the best option in most cases. The point of SE is to give the questioner an answer, yes, but it is also a place where other people can find answers to their problems... You decide which answer should be accepted, I just thought Mayhem's was better.

Comment: there is now right answer to this question so i just used mine because it suited me best

Comment: Ok. Then you choose that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have the option of export to QuickTime - which is pretty widely used. And even if you don't like those format options you can convert to something else easily from there.

Comment: I can see the option of output it in mov (btw Quick Time is a software, not a format ;-D ) but I can't access it, would i need to install QuickTime ... I'm on windows. 
Since I don't want to reconvert again though, this is only half en option. It is a perfectly valid option but i seek something else. What I don't get is why they couldn't use any standard avi codec since avi is at least a standard container and would be supported by most players if they had chosen a standard codec.

Comment: Yes, the option in GoPro is export to QuickTime. Mov is a standard - not one of my preferred ones, as QuickTime is a buggy, bloated POS, but most video editing software will cope with it perfectly well.

Comment: I did upvote now for your answer

Comment: I agree with your view on QuickTime and I won't have it on my pc.